# How to check ASP.NET CheckBoxList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms

I am using ASP.NET CheckBoxList for multi selection of Items and I am binding this CheckBoxList  on server side on page load and I have one input button as Edit Button and I want to display checked check box list item on click of Edit Button. For that I am trying Like this:

Check box

```html
<div id="checkboxplant" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkPlantsAddNew" CssClass="MyClass" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList></div>
```

AJAX

```
   function OnSuccessRecordCall(data, status) {
        result = Record;
        if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
            var checkboxList = $("[id*=chkPlantsAddNew]");
            checkboxList.each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == $.trim(result.PLANT_CODE_EDIT)) {
                        $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

DOM for 1st and 2nd table row

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_0" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$0"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_0">1001</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_1" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$1"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_1">CPP</label></td>
</tr>
```

While debugging on browser I can see CheckBoxList value is not displaying any value its simply showing `""` string. Why so? I don't know why it so?

Kindly see below screen shots, In that I have selected my 1st `tr` for that text is 1001 and value is 0 but while debugging we are getting empty string so due this I am not able to checked my particular Items?

[image]

Kindly help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `value` you have highlighted is the value of the `part` property of a `table` element. It has nothing to do with the value of the CheckBoxList. I think you may be selecting the incorrect DOM element that represents the selected values of the CheckBoxList, but it's been a long time since I worked with Web Forms.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the rendered HTML for the CheckBoxList as code-formatted text, rather than a picture. Then we might be able to tell you what the correct DOM element to select is.

Comment: OK i am updating same in my question

Comment: @HereticMonkey Kindly check my Updated Question I have updated DOM for check box list row Items

Comment: Well, from that you can see that the checkboxes do not have a `value` attribute set, so searching for `$(this).val() == ` will not match anything.  This was a problem with Web Forms; Microsoft didn't pay any attention to how HTML should be used, and just output enough HTML that it looked okay and they could match on the backend. I'm assuming that the value you're looking for is "1001" or "CPP" or one of those visible amounts?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree `$(this).val() ==` is not matching anything So i am not able to check. But from backend i.e on server side i am setting both text field as well as Value Field to `checkboxlist` but why value field is not rendering on HTML. is there any other alternate to achieve same ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function here which will check a checkbox in any CheckBoxList that has a label with a given value. So you shouldn't need to loop or anything; it will find checkboxes with labels that contain the text of the given value, and check that checkbox.

I didn't get how the rest of your code works, but this should be enough to get you on your way.

The buttons are just examples to show the function works.

```js
function checkCheckboxWithValue(value) {
  $('input:checkbox + label').filter(':contains("' + value + '")').prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
}
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  checkCheckboxWithValue(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_0" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$0"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_0">1001</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_1" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$1"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_1">CPP</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="chk1001">1001</button>
<button id="chkCPP">CPP</button>
```

Comment: I tried your code but its thronging error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

Comment: The snippet is not throwing an error in Chrome 89...

Comment: I tried with internet Explorer there i am getting same error `SCRIPT5009: 'value' is undefined` can you please suggest me any other alternate as i can see snippet is working as expected

Comment: What version of IE? I was able to run the code in IE11 with no issue. If you are using a version older than 11 you're running an insecure version of the browser, and I can't really help you with that.

Comment: that error i resolved but instead of setting only 2 items its selecting all check box list item. it seams filter is not working

Comment: my Ajax method returning two fields 'PlantCode' and `userID` and on basis of `Plant Code` i want to select respected items

Comment: There's no ajax in the code you've shared. I've answered the question as it was originally asked. If you have another question, please ask another question. Please do read [ask] before doing so, however, as you seem to be leaving out a fair amount of necessary information from your questions, only to reveal it in comments, which is not where that information should be.